# Plotting a symbolic function with multiple variables in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, sympy

First code cell:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sympy as sym
from ipywidgets.widgets import interact
sym.init_printing(use_latex="mathjax")
x, y, z, t = sym.symbols('x y z t')
```

I am required to plot the following function which I have defined as:

```
p_w = (1/sym.sqrt(sym.pi*(1-sym.exp(-2*t))))*sym.exp(-(z-sym.exp(-t))**2/(1-sym.exp(-2*t)))
```

Obviously t and z are both variables and I am to plot the function for t = 0.1,1, and 10, using z as my x-axis and p_w(z) as the y-axis.

I tried defining 3 functions j,k,l with the values subbed in for t like so:

```
j=p_w.evalf(subs={t:0.1})
k=p_w.evalf(subs={t:1})
l=p_w.evalf(subs={t:10})
```

then changing these to numpy arrays with the sym.lambdify() function:

```
j_np=sym.lambdify(z,j)
k_np=sym.lambdify(z,k)
l_np=sym.lambdify(z,l)
```

I defined my x-axis using:

```
myz = np.linspace(0,10,1000)
```

(The 1000 divisions was fairly arbitrary as I wasn't sure how many I'd need for an accurate graph)

Then I tried plotting just j to begin with as follows:

```
plt.plot(myz, j_np(myz))
```

and got the following error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call     last)
<ipython-input-41-d743a8a00bcf> in <module>()
----> 1 plt.plot(myz,j_np(myz))

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py in <lambda>.   (_Dummy_164)

AttributeError: 'Mul' object has no attribute 'exp'
```

I am guessing the problem is that numpy does not understand 'exp' in the same way that sympy does, but I am unsure as to how to rectify it, or even if this is the problem at all. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this to work if you skip the `evalf` step:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sympy as sym
from ipywidgets.widgets import interact
sym.init_printing(use_latex="mathjax")
# x, y, z, t = sym.symbols('x y z t')
from sympy.abc import x,y,z,t

p_w = (1/sym.sqrt(sym.pi*(1-sym.exp(-2*t))))*sym.exp(-(z - sym.exp(-t))**2/(1-sym.exp(-2*t)))
myz = np.linspace(0,10,1000)

lam=sym.lambdify((z,t), p_w)

myz = np.linspace(0,10,1000)
times = [.01, 1, 10]

for time in times:
    plt.plot(myz, lam(myz, time))
```

Output:

[image]

It seems the underlying issue was that setting the time using `p_w.evalf(subs={t:0.1})` doesn't really work:

```
print(p_w.evalf(subs={t:0.1}))

0.564189583547756*(1.0 - exp(-2*t))**(-0.5)*exp(-(z - exp(-t))**2/(1 - exp(-2*t)))
```

It works right if `z` is removed from `p_w`:

```
p_w = (1/sym.sqrt(sym.pi*(1-sym.exp(-2*t))))*sym.exp(-(- sym.exp(-t))**2/(1-sym.exp(-2*t)))
print(p_w.evalf(subs={t:0.1})) 

0.0144778612224441
```

So apparently having the undetermined variable `z` in `p_w` prevents `p_w.evalf` from expanding the `t` terms correctly.